# Start animation on mouseleave and stop on mouseenter using setinterval and clearinterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval, materialize, clearinterval

I'm using the materialize carousel and it's changing slides automatically using setInterval() but i want that this setInterval should stop / pause on hover and restart on unhover.

I have tried using clearinterval but it's not working perfectly.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.carousel').carousel(); // Start carousel

    /*  I WAS USING THIS BEFORE JUST FOR CHANGING SLIDES AUTOMATICALLY
    setInterval(function(){
        $('.carousel').carousel('next');
    },2500);
    });
    */

    // THIS IS WHAT IHAVE TRIED

    var myVar;

    function start(){
        var myVar = setInterval(next, 2500);
        function next() {
            $('.carousel').carousel('next');
        }
    }

    function stop() {
        clearInterval(myVar);
        myVar = 0;
    }

    $('.carousel').mouseenter(function(){stop();});
    $('.carousel').mouseleave(function(){start();});

    start();
});
```

The code is not giving any error.

Comment: Remove the `var` from `var myVar` inside the `start` function. As it is you have two variables named `myVar` one inside the function and one in outer scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this line:

```
var myVar = setInterval(next, 2500);
```

with this:

```
myVar = setInterval(next, 2500);
```

You have defined the global variable and in your `start` function, you are again initializing the variable and assigning the return value of `setInterval` to it. That means `myVar` remains unassigned for the remaining code except for the `start` function. so `clearInterval` does not work.

You just need to assign the return value to the global variable `myVar` and that works for you.